# Ajax Form Submission & Javascript Confirm Error

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have a form that submits through Ajax, which works perfectly at the moment. I tried to add a confirm option to allow / prevent the Ajax submission through adding the following lines:

```
    var answer = confirm('Submit now?');
    return answer // answer is a boolean

    if(answer) { ... }
```

Below is my full function, which, as you can see, fires on clicking the submit button. The error occurs when the user selects okay in the dialog. The entire page is refreshed and any single Ajax warnings are returned at the top of a blank screen. In a normal case, without this confirm code, the error messages appear in the div#result tag at the bottom of the form.

```
$("#submitbtn").click(function() {

        var answer = confirm('Submit now?');
        return answer // answer is a boolean

        if(answer) { 

            $('#result').html('<img id="loading" src="images/loading.gif" />').fadeIn();
            var input_data = $('#create_po').serialize();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url:  "<?php echo "http://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>",
                data: input_data,
                success: function(msg){
                    $('#loading').remove();
                    $('<div>').html(msg).appendTo('div#result').hide().fadeIn('slow');
                }
            });
            return false;

        }

    });
```

How should I implement a confirm dialog that doesn't refresh the screen? Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: If you `return answer` what is after this line will not be executed. don't return answer.

Comment: Why don't you use jquery ui dialog to show the confirmation. http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/

Comment: @Scorpion-Prince that would have him include another full javascript library, asuming he doesn't. Don't include if there is no really good reason ;) Confirm box will do just fine

Comment: @Topener completely agree, just that confirm prompts like javascript alerts locks the browser and doesn't let the user move to other tabs. They generally cause bad user experience. Using a dialog, need not necessarily be jquery-ui, is a more elegant way, IMHO. But, if it is only in one page, it is probably better to use a confirm prompt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing `return answer`. Which doesn't make any sense here.

It will stop the JavaScript function, and will return the boolean. Remove this line, and you're set

Also, add this to make your submit not fireing if the confirm box is false ;)

```
if (answer){
    // your ajax call
}
else {
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not use this:

```
<input type="submit">
```

Use this:

```
<input type="button">
```

A submit button automatically submits a form. A regular button does nothing. You can use that to listen for clicks and THEN submit your form, or not.

Comment: Not to mention if that were the case then you could just override the `submit` functionality.

Comment: If you're using JavaScript to submit the form, you shouldn't use the submit button; you should use a button. This is a best practice. No, my answer didn't solve his problem, but you shouldn't enable a button and then disable it for no reason.

Comment: What part of what I said wasn't true? Please explain or undo the downvote. A submit button is an HTML form element that submits forms. Are you suggesting that this is untrue?